# Lua - Unable to assign property Value. string expected, got Instance

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

Anyone knows how to fix this. I have tried so many things and i could not find a fix to this problem

```
lasthit = tick()

    cd = true
            
    anim.AnimationId = swingAmins[combo]
    local load = c.Humanoid:LoadAnimation(anim):Play()
    
    local data = {char = c, comboN = combo, action = "slash"}
    remote:FireServer(data)
    slash(c, combo)
    
    if combo == 5 then
        combo = 1
    else
        combo = combo + 1
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only assign a string to `anim.AnimationId`. According to the error message `swingAmins[combo]` is an Instance, probably an Animation.

See https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Animation/AnimationId

Maybe you intended to do something like this:

```
anim.AnimationId = swingAmins[combo].AnimationId
```

Comment: That also didn't work. Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: didn't work is not very informative. I cannot solve this for you. you are the one who should know which AnimationId you need and where it comes from.